# Como exibir valores cadastrados em uma planilha do Google Drive em outra através de consulta por JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-excel

Tenho uma tabela no Google Drive e desejo usar Scripts para fazer oque desejo para ficar de uma maneira mais dinâmica.

Na Pagina2, tenho os campos de "Resultado" "Atraso" e "Chegada" com os seus devidos resultados preenchidos abaixo, eu desejo criar na Página1 em um campo, um select que consulte na Página2, nos campos de Resultado, Atraso e Chegada e me mostre os registros cadastrados na Página2, na coluna ao lado de onde seleciona o campo(no caso os resultados deverão vir na coluna B1 e o termo procurado ficar na coluna A1 com a sétinha do select).

[image: Página1 -consulta de resultados (quero o resultado na coluna B)]
[image: Pagina 2 com os registrados que desejo mostrar cadastrados]

Answer (score 1):

Se você quiser pegar os dados de uma folha em outra use isso: ([fonte](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/75943?hl=en))

```
// Pega o conteúdo da A1 na Sheet1:
=Sheet1!A1

// Caso a folha tenha espaços no nome use isso:
='Sheet number two'!B4
```

*Continuando a resposta, de acordo com o que o autor quer:*

Na célula A1 use a [validação de dados para criar um campo](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/186103?hl=pt).
Na célula B2 use a função `lookup()`:

```
// Documentação:
=LOOKUP(celula com a caixa de selecao, celulas com o título, celulas com os dados)

// Utilização:
=LOOKUP($A$1, Sheet2!$A$1:$B$1, Sheet2!$A2:$B2)
```

Onde `Sheet2` é o nome da folha onde estão os dados. Então puxe a célula B2 para baixo preenchendo as outras células que irão mostrar os dados da outra folha.

Comment: Amigo, insiro este código onde? Eu não manjo de Excel, estou tentando descobrir como fazer, me pediram e creio que consigo...Obrigado desde já!!

Comment: Não desejo apenas os dados, desejo que seja um select que tenha os campos RESULTADO/ATRASO/CHEGADA no campo A1 e que os dados registrados abaixo de RESULTADO/ATRASO/CHEGADA apareçam no campo B1 ao lado

Comment: Entendi errado. BTW Google Drive é bem diferente de Excel. Vou editar minha resposta.

Comment: Cara, tentei de diversas formas...como que seria para salvar os itens da listas? Não consegui fazer não, só me aparece "#ERROR!" quando jogo o código "=LOOKUP($A$1, Página2!$A$1:$B$1, Página2!$A2:$B2)"

Comment: A versão do Google Docs que você está usando em essa função? É a versão atualizada (New Google Spreadsheets)?